# Is update_post_meta used when save_post action hook is invoked?

Tags: posts, hooks, actions, api

Here, I have some code which applies some indexing operations on an external service (Algolia).
My purpose, is to index posts in a similar way, as described in their API [documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/integration/wordpress/indexing/automatic-updates/?language=php).
For that cause, I have set up two action hooks:

```
add_action('save_post', 'algolia_save_post', 10, 3);
```

and

```
add_action('trashed_post','algolia_trash_post', 10, 1);
```

While this works as expected, I noticed that, in case metadata are altered, such as permalinks, the data are not updated in the index.
I then tried the `update_post_meta` action hook:

```
add_action('update_post_meta', 'algolia_update_post_meta', 10, 4);
```

Which seems to do the job well. However, I suspect that update_post_meta is invoked both when metadata fields are altered, but also on `save_post` chain.

As I do not want to achieve a double, redundant indexing on article save I would like to ask, is the addition of the indexing code in the `update_post_meta` considered always on post save? In that case, I can remove the `save_post` hook and keep only this of meta. What I want to avoid, is the loss of index update in any case of the post update operations (excluding auto-save).

My local testing showed that, by adding the code only in the meta hook, everything works well and index gets updated on any field, yet I am not sure if there is an edge case I miss.

While this question involves the usage of an third-part vendor (Algolia), I believe it can be answered by a WordPress expert. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `update_post_meta` will always be called when post metadata changes. If you closely check algolia documentation, you would see they are only updating post fields (title, content, status) etc with `save_post` hook. And they are updating post meta data with `update_post_meta` hook. Post fields & post meta both are different type of data.

Comment: @Shazzad I know both things are different and for a different purpose, but I want to know if `update_post_meta` is invoked within `save_post` action chain at some point.
That way, I could attach the index update only in `update_post_meta`, in order to avoid redundant, duplicate index update.

Comment: By default, the action hook `update_post_meta` does not get invoked within `save_post` hook. But, if you (or any plugin) add an action on `save_post`, and call `update_post_meta()` function inside that callback, then `update_post_meta` hook will be fired for each usage.

Comment: Ok, if you are sure about this, please add it comprehensively as an answer so that I accept it. Thank you.